# Fsharp CSV parsing

Tags: csv, f#, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I'm trying to get this to work
http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html

But to me it seems like tha CsvFile class and the CSVextionson are removed of the Data lib

I'm running it on Manjaro (Arclinux system)

I'm using the mono compiler (fsharpc)
I got the dotnet core lib

So nothing should be wrong

please help

EDITED

Code

```
open FSharp.Data

let msft = CsvFile.Load("https://github.com/kam1986/Data-Science-project/blob/master/news_sample.csv")
```

It is placed in a .fsx file

get hte error message
Fake News.fsx(3,14): error FS0039: The value, namespace, type or module 'CsvFile' is not defined.

Comment: What makes you think they have been removed?

Comment: What's your code? What error do you get?

Comment: It seems like it should work. I know that library has been upgraded to work with .NET Core. Follow the instructions carefully. Using a Type Provider might work differently than you are expecting, but once you get it to work, I think you'll be thrilled with it.

Comment: The same as that in the link.

but with the fsharpc (mono) compiler and monodevelop i got the same error message
Fake News.fsx(3,14): error FS0039: The value, namespace, type or module 'CsvFile' is not defined.